# Changing Package name for an application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I need to deploy two application on the play store :

Eg: 
**com.android.myapppro** and **com.android.myappfree** both have similar code but small changes like [Show/Hide Ads]

So while changing the package name of the application updating the Gradle file

```
applicationId "com.android.myapppro"
```

**To**

```
    applicationId "com.android.myappfree"
```

is sufficient, or do i need to update the **AndroidManifest.xml** also.

Changing the **AndroidManifest.xml** will force me to update the **R** imports in all the classes.

Please Help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)

> Therefore, we have decoupled the two usages of package name:
>
> - The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play
>     store, is the "application id".
> - The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations,
>     continues to be called the "package".

You need to change only `applicaitonId` and left `AndroidManifest.xml` as is.